# Schema for matches/events/fights?

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a `fighters` table, an `events` table and I'm creating a `fights` table.

I want to track the event, all fighters ( 1 on 1 fights ), (optional) judges and (optional) referees in a fight. The fields which are optional are so because I won't always have this information.

How should I design the schema for this? Since each fight has more than one, its many, so does that mean I should create a mapping table? Eg:

**fights**

```
id   event_id     promotion_id
-----------------------

1    7            9
```

**fights_fighters**

```
id   fighter_id
-----------------------
1    3
1    4
```

**fighters**

```
id   name
-----------------------
3    Fedor Emelianenko
4    Fabricio Werdum
```

**events**

```
id   name                                date
-----------------------

7    Strikeforce! Fedor vs Werdum        2010-06-26
```

**promotions**

```
id   name
-----------------------

9    Strikeforce
```

Would a schema like this make sense? Since there are only 2 fighters ever in a fight, I initially just thought of making a `fighter_a` and `fighter_b` column in the `fights` table and not even have a `fights_fighters` table.

1. Could anyone offer insight into the pros/cons of having a fights_fighters mapping table vs just having the fighter a/b columns?
2. I want to track how fights end. They can end either in a) Knockouts b) Decisions c) Submissions d) Stoppages - where/how can I embed fight endings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As you mentioned with a fights_fighters table you have trouble enforcing the rule that a fight is only two fighters.  But it's difficult to query a table with fighter_a and fighter_b columns to find all the fights for a fighter.

With the fights_fighters table you could add an entry for referee and judges by expanding the fighter table with a type (fighter, referee or judge) and the fights_fighter table would then require two fighters, zero to x judges, and zero to x referees for each fight.  Maye that becomes a fights_person table with the person table having types of fighter, referee or judge.

2) How the fight ends would be in the fights table.  You could just use a text or numeric field with values you've predefined or you could include a foreign key to a results table.  If you expect other possible results like suspended or withdrew then create the results table so you can add other results without changing the database.  Also wouldn't you also have to record which fighter won the fight?